# Gazebo 1.2~1.3 Plugin for ROS

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to use PR2 with new gazebo 1.3 on ubuntu 12.04 and ros-fuerte.
The specific purpose is to test contact sensors all over the robot surface (tactile sensing).

As long as I know gazebo 1.3 is stand alone program, so I need ROS-Enabled Gazebo Model Plugin for PR2.

From below link's answer, I read that there is no plugin for PR2 now.
If my understanding is correct, I have to make my own plugin over entire PR2 functions.
Is it correct? or Does it mean impossible to make the plugin for ros now?

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/112/error-from-launching-pr2launch/

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/474/gazebo-1.2%7E1.3-plugin-for-ros/) by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 47 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That is correct, you'll need to make your own PR2 plugin until an official ROS plugin is released.
You can make Gazebo plugins that talk ROS.

Take a look at the DRC simulator package for examples: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1